# Acceso externo a un mysql container en docker sobre plesk

Tags: mysql, docker, plesk

Estoy tratando de configurar una base de datos MySQL para usarla externamente. Tengo un servidor Ubuntu con Plesk y Docker.

El problema principal es que el puerto parece estar usado/abierto cuando estoy conectado al servidor, pero no externamente.

Configuración del contenedor MySQL: [mysql container settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdkrt.png)

Cuando intento iniciar sesión localmente, no hay problema, ya que muestra que el puerto 6991 está abierto.

```
root@server:/# nmap -p 6990-6992 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-13 09:37 UTC
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000034s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6990/tcp open   unknown
6991/tcp open   unknown
6992/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds
```

Cuando ejecuto el mismo nmap desde una máquina externa:

```
user2@server2:/# nmap -p 6990-6992 [public ip]
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-13 09:45 UTC
Nmap scan report for [URL] ([public ip])
Host is up (0.000085s latency).
Other addresses for [URL] (not scanned):

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
6990/tcp closed unknown
6991/tcp closed unknown
6992/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.14 seconds
```

Los puertos 6991 y 6990 del firewall del proveedor del servidor también están abiertos.

He intentado comprobar los puertos para iniciar un servidor HTTP Python simple y esto funciona.

```
root@server:/# docker stop mysql
mysql
root@server:/# python3 -m http.server 6991
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 6991 (http://0.0.0.0:6991/) ...
```

```
user2@server2:/# nmap -p 6991 [public ip]
Starting Nmap 7.94 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-10-13 11:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for [URL] ([public ip])
Host is up (0.020s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
6991/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.36 seconds
```

¿Quizás haya alguna magia de Plesk que esté bloqueando el puerto?

Comment: falta informacion, como por ejemplo el cliente esta dentro de un docker?
has un grafico de como esta y otro de como deberia funcionar.
te dejo la pagina https://app.diagrams.net/  quiza asi se organice la idea

Comment: He descubierto que es debido a una actualizacion de mediados de setiembre de la extension de docker para Plesk